# Getting into the trending list

Tags: google-play-store

What are the criteria being used to decide which apps go into the trending apps lists on Google Play?

When I look on the trending lists, I don't see a lot of consistency. I see apps with as little as a 1000-5000 downloads and others with 500K-1M downloads.

I guess the real question is, any idea what Google takes into consideration when deciding what's trending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This explanation is inferred from [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com)'s 3rd tab: **Distribute**. In that section, it is clearly taught how Google gets an app in [Trending portion](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/about/visibility.html).

The main factors are: ratings, downloads and great apps that users are providing a great feedback with are mainly on the top of the Trending Apps, but there are two type of trending app sections, Free and Paid. So make sure you are viewing the section that is mainly for you.

That's all what Google would use:

1. Feedback
2. Ratings
3. Downloads
4. Content